# Can caffine cache removal listener may get called multiple times(concurrently) for the same entry

Tags: java, caching, guava, caffeine-cache

Can caffine cache removal listener may get called multiple times(concurrently) for the same entry.
Lets say Entry<Key,Value> is removed.
Can removal listener run multiple times(concurrently)for this Value?

My expectation is that removal listener thead will pick this Value only once and no two thread will get this Value.

Comment: The call to `Caffeine.removalListener` will be submitted to the executor once per removal operation. A remove-add-remove sequence would submit two tasks and the executor would run them as it saw fit (maybe in parallel). If sequential ordering matters, consider `Caffeine.evictionListener` instead. That is called atomically during the removal operation on the calling thread but it only covers `wasEvicted()` scenarios. For explicit removals you can use `asMap().compute` to call your custom logic within the operation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, take a look at the [GitHub](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine?tab=readme-ov-file#cache) documentation.

> Caffeine provides an in-memory cache using a Google Guava inspired API. The improvements draw on our experience designing Guava's cache and ConcurrentLinkedHashMap.

Comment: "You may specify a removal listener for your cache to perform some operation when an entry is removed, via Caffeine.removalListener(RemovalListener). These operations are executed asynchronously using an Executor, where the default executor is ForkJoinPool.commonPool() and can be overridden via Caffeine.executor(Executor)."  But there is no mentioning of removal listener thread picking the Value only once